# Websphere JAX-WS web service client using RAD does not allow Java Project

Tags: java, jax-ws, webservice-client, rad, websphere-7

I am trying to create a web service client using RAD 7.5 using JAX-WS run time / Websphere 7.

However RAD does not allow to select a Java Project as "Client Project" when using JAX-WS (If run time is selected as JAX-RPC it allows to select Java Project)

Why does RAD force me to define my JAX-WS web service client inside a WAR project.

Is there any way for me to create the web service client as a plain Java project?

Comment: This does not seem to be a limitation of RAD 7.5.4; you might want to search for an APAR for this.

Comment: This does not work RAD 8.0.4. Whenever i try to create jax-ws client with wsdl in a java project, i dont see version number dropdown on jax-ws client wizard. However if i keep my wsdl in web-inf and i try to create the client, i see the version number dropdown and my code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a little trick for that (its probably a defect).

When you click Generate client and the wizard opens do the following:

Click the `Client project` link, manually enter a random string (e.g. xxx), you will be able to select the `Java utility project` project type.

Click OK, then click the `Client project` again and you will be able to select any project you want.

- Tested on RAD 8.0.4

Comment: Interesting. This works. I wonder how you figured out this trick :)